# Resetting Programmatically adding buttons for UITableViewCell Reuse

Tags: swift3, uitableview

In my tableview controller. The images are being added as backgrounds to the button. These buttons are then added to the table view cell on user requirement. 
If i show/hide the cell. The buttons with background images from the hidden cell are being shown on the enabled row/cell i.e. overlapping. I have read articles regarding prepareforReuse function. Which can be used if i know the existing properties. In my app the buttons are being added based on user selection.

Is there any way to use prepareforReuse to reset every thing even the buttons which have been added programmatically so that when they are called then overlapping issue doesnt appear. 
Main Problem: I cannot give names of my buttons to set their values as nil because i dont know how many will be created. While in prepareforReuse (to reset the cell) i need to provide some property names which exist in cells already.

Comment: Simple rule according to the model-view-controller pattern (MVC). Create a model (the data source array) which mirrors all states in the cell. Do not manipulate the view (the cell). The **controller** is supposed to manipulate the **model** and then to reload the **view**.